# Some Very unClear tag: drop [svc] for ambiguity since 2013

Tags: discussion, retag-request

There are 249 questions tagged with [svc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/svc). I don't think it's ready for *burnination*, but it doesn't seem helpful.

The [svc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/svc) info states:

> This tag is ambiguous. Consider using the video-encoding tag for Scalable Video Coding, or the wcf and/or iis tags for the Microsoft file extension.

And every edit in [the svc wiki's history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/15054847/revisions) is "*by the way, this also could mean...*"

---

These should probably be retagged along these lines:

- Scalable Video Coding → [video-encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/video-encoding)
- The .svc file used by Microsoft → [iis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/iis), [wcf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wcf)
- Supervisor mode of a process → (Unsure, a few questions are co-tagged with [arm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arm) `SVC_Handler` implementations)
- Support Vector Classification in sciki-learn → [scikit-learn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scikit-learn), [svm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/svm)

Comment: It is also used for services, e.g. [web-services] (maybe also mvc..?).

Comment: Is there any reason to keep any questions with this tag? If not, what is the difference to a burnination?

Answer (score 4):

Yeah, should get split, not burninated.

- (status: done): The [arm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arm) assembly questions should be retagged [system-calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/system-calls) and/or [interrupt-handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/interrupt-handling) if appropriate. `svc` is the name of an ARM instruction (SuperVisor Call) that traps into the kernel, like x86 or MIPS `syscall` or x86 `sysenter`.
- Video encoding questions should get tagged [h.264](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/h.264), and maybe [video-encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/video-encoding) if there's room and the question is about *encoding*, rather than streaming existing files or decoding / playback.  [Scalable Video Coding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Video_Coding) is an extension to AVC, aka H.264.

  Possibly also [x264](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/x264) or [libx264](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/libx264) or whatever tag about a specific encoder producing SVC files.  (Should those tags be synonyms?)